# node vue require library for use in component

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am getting new to using vue.js with components a requiring libraries using NPM.

So far I use gulp Vueify to compile my core code along with .vue files into a bundle.js file. It works with my components but when adding something like Axios it cant find the library.

So I did `NPM install axios --save-dev` that got me the library.

Then my vueCore.js file

```
var $               = require("jquery")
var Vue             = require('vue')
var axios           = require('axios')
var contentList     = require('./components/content-list.vue')
var heroHeader      = require('./components/hero-header.vue')

new Vue({
    el: '#page',
    components: {
        'dashboard-view': dashboard,    
        'content-list': contentList,
        'hero-header': heroHeader
    }
})
```

then when I try and use axios in `dashboard` component

```
mounted:  function() {

            axios.get('/custom_api/api_home_get.php?', {
                params: {
                  ID: i4
                }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                this.last = response;
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
}
```

then I get all the component elements with an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must require('axios') in every component you want to use it.

But the way I prefer, is to set up Vue.prototype.$http with axios.
So, before declaring your Vue app, you declare

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

then axios will be available in any of your components without the need of importing it.

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$http.get('/whatever').then(whatever)
    ...
}
```

Source: [vue-resource retirement](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4#.asa3a58y5)

Comment: That worked. Is there not a way to just did it once since it will just used in a lot of components?

Comment: You can setup 'prototype' to contain anything you want, so all your components will inherit it. In my study project I have axios and snackbar.js in prototype.